# Building a report of DNA sites and chunks

Tags: python, performance, csv, formatting, bioinformatics

Here is the slow part of my code:

```
def Prepare_WCfst_file():
    content_WCfst = "iteration\tlocus\tFromSite\tToSite\tWCFst\n"
    nbchunks = nbsites/nbsitesPerChunk
    if nbchunks%1 != 0:
        print("\n\nThe number of sites per chunk for WCFst is not a divisor of the number of sites per locus.\nProcess is aborted!\n\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    nbchunks = int(nbchunks)
    nbsitesPerChunk_minus1 = nbsitesPerChunk - 1
    for iteration in xrange(nbiterations):
        for locus in xrange(nbloci):
            FromSite = 0
            ToSite = nbsitesPerChunk_minus1
            for chunk in xrange(nbchunks):
                content_WCfst += str(iteration) + "\t" + str(locus) + "\t" + str(FromSite) + "\t" + str(ToSite) + "\n"
                FromSite = ToSite + 1
                ToSite = FromSite + nbsitesPerChunk_minus1
    return content_WCfst
```

Typically, `nbiterations` and `nbloci` take values between 1 and 100. `nbchunks` however can take values of the order of 10^6 to 10^9. This function will be called about 100 to 10,000 times in total.

**Suggested data to benchmark**

```
nbloci = 10^6
nbiterations = 20
nbloci = 2
nbsitesPerChunk = 10
```

**What the function does**

Basically, what this piece of code does is to create a long string `content_WCfst` (which will afterward be written on a file). The file needs to contain 4 columns: `iteration`, `locus`, `FromSite` and `ToSite`. The difference between the columns `FromSite` and `ToSite` is always `nbsitesPerChunk_minus1`. By the end the number of lines is `nbiterations * nbloci * nbchunks`.

**My thoughts about what to improve**

I think the part that can be improved is the three loops or eventually only the most internal loop (`for chunk in xrange(nbchunks):`)

Note that I've tried to replace

```
str(iteration) + "\t" + str(locus) + "\t" + str(FromSite) + "\t" + str(ToSite) + "\n"
```

by

```
"\t".join(str(iteration), str(locus), str(FromSite), str(ToSite), "\n")
```

but it was even slower.

Note also that the function doesn't receive any arguments and therefore, all parameters are defined globally outside this function. I don't expect it to be an issue as they are not called over and over again.

I am hoping that a solution can exist so that the looping occurs in C, using NumPy eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use `snake_case` for most names. Whilst `prepare_WCfst_file` is allowed, `Prepare_WCfst_file` is not.
- Pass varibles, don't depend on ones out of scope.
- Lines should be 79 characters max.
  The exception is comments at 72.

You have a very good style otherwise!

---

You are using archaic string formatting.

```
content_WCfst += str(iteration) + "\t" + str(locus) + "\t" + str(FromSite) + "\t" + str(ToSite) + "\n"
```

Use `format` instead.

```
content_WCfst += "{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\n".format(iteration, locus, FromSite, ToSite)
```

---

```
for iteration in xrange(nbiterations):
    for locus in xrange(nbloci):
        for chunk in xrange(nbchunks):
```

I think the above is the offending factor. This is as it is \$O(n^3)\$.

But not only that you are appending to what can be a massive list. The append, may seem small early on, but later use a lot of cpu.

To fix this you can change the function to a generator. The thing `xrange` is.

**Pros**

- Fast.
- On demand output.
- Low memory usage.
- Can be used like a list in most cases.

**Cons**

- If you bin the output, is worse than a list.
- Can't be duplicated.
- Can't be index or sliced. `[1]` or `[:2]` do not work.

It's simple.

```
content_WCfst += "{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\n".format(iteration, locus, FromSite, ToSite)
# To
yield "{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\n".format(iteration, locus, FromSite, ToSite)
```

If you can't use a generator, then `set`s are also good. However they can only store hashable data, and one of it. And don't keep order.

```
>>> set(['a', 'c', 'a', 'b'])
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

To implement this:

```
content_WCfst += "{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\n".format(iteration, locus, FromSite, ToSite)
# To
content_WCfst.add("{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\t{!s}\n".format(iteration, locus, FromSite, ToSite))
```

This is if `content_WCfst` is also a set.

---

I can't think of a way to solve the \$O(n^3)\$ part.
However adding to lists and strings are very slow compared to sets and generators.

Comment: `.format` is faster than string sum and a generator will avoid double memory use as he wants to save it to a fle, nice!

Answer (score 5):

```
nbchunks = nbsites/nbsitesPerChunk
if nbchunks%1 != 0:
    print("\n\nThe number of sites per chunk for WCFst is not a divisor of the number of sites per locus.\nProcess is aborted!\n\n")
    sys.exit(1)
nbchunks = int(nbchunks)
```

This chunk of code is not good because:

```
nbchunks = nbsites / nbsitesPerChunk
```

In python-2 is already int for sure, in Python-3 you can write:

```
nbchunks = nbsites // nbsitesPerChunk
```

and it will be int for sure, so you can remove

```
nbchunks = int(nbchunks)
```

to avoid clutter.

---

The line:

```
if nbchunks%1 != 0
```

- (minor) should be spaced like `if nbchunks % 1 != 0`
- (SERIOUS) is always false as the remainder between a natural number and one is always zero!

---

Also the error message:

```
print("\n\nThe number of sites per chunk for WCFst is not a divisor of the number of sites per locus.\nProcess is aborted!\n\n")
```

is not connected to the `if` statement...

---

Exiting explicit like `sys.exit(1)` should be avoided, you should instead:

```
raise AdequateException(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python are immutable, so string concatenation is expensive.  If you need to concatenate strings, then build a list and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the elements at the end.  Alternatively, `yield` each line from a generator.

Better yet, use a [CSV writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) with <kbd>Tab</kbd> as the delimiter, since that is just the kind of output that you are generating.